# Spark is not able to resolve the columns correctly when joins data frames

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark, databricks

I'm using pyspark ( python 3.8) over spark3.0 on Databricks. When running this DataFrame join:

```py
next_df = (
    days_currencies_matrix.alias("a")
    .join(
        data_to_merge.alias("b"),
        [
            days_currencies_matrix.dt == data_to_merge.RATE_DATE,
            days_currencies_matrix.CURRENCY_CODE == data_to_merge.CURRENCY_CODE,
        ],
        "LEFT",
    )
    .select(
        days_currencies_matrix.CURRENCY_CODE,
        days_currencies_matrix.dt.alias("RATE_DATE"),
        data_to_merge.AVGYTD,
        data_to_merge.ENDMTH,
        data_to_merge.AVGMTH,
        data_to_merge.AVGWEEK,
        data_to_merge.AVGMTD,
    )
)
```

And I’m getting this error:

> Column AVGYTD#67187, AVGWEEK#67190, ENDMTH#67188, AVGMTH#67189, AVGMTD#67191 are ambiguous. It's probably because you joined several Datasets together, and some of these Datasets are the same. This column points to one of the Datasets but Spark is unable to figure out which one. Please alias the Datasets with different names via `Dataset.as` before joining them, and specify the column using qualified name, e.g. `df.as("a").join(df.as("b"), $"a.id" > $"b.id")`. You can also set spark.sql.analyzer.failAmbiguousSelfJoin to false to disable this check.

Which is telling me that the above columns belong to more than one dataset. Why is that happening? The code is telling to spark exactly the source dataframe;
also, the days_currencies_matrix has only 2 columns: dt and CURRENCY_CODE.

The source data frames are defined as follow:

```
currencies_in_merging_data = data_to_merge.select('CURRENCY_CODE').distinct()

days_currencies_matrix = dt_days.crossJoin(currencies_in_merging_data)
```

Is it because days_currencies_matrix DataFrame actually is built over the data_to_merge? Is that something related to Lazy evaluations or it is a bug?

BTW, this version works with no issues:

```py
next_df = (
    days_currencies_matrix.alias("a")
    .join(
        data_to_merge.alias("b"),
        [
            days_currencies_matrix.dt == data_to_merge.RATE_DATE,
            days_currencies_matrix.CURRENCY_CODE == data_to_merge.CURRENCY_CODE,
        ],
        "LEFT",
    )
    .select(
        col("a.dt").alias("RATE_DATE"),
        col("a.CURRENCY_CODE"),
        col("b.AVGYTD"),
        col("b.ENDMTH"),
        col("b.AVGMTH"),
        col("b.AVGWEEK"),
        col("b.AVGMTD"),
    )
)
```

Comment: The error is quite explicit. Spark says that you should use an alias when calling the columns. This is why the second version of your code works. You are doing exactly what spark needs you to do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is solving the problem within the question by following exactly the instructions in the error message.

Comment: @Steven: data_to_merge.AVGYTD is that not enough?

Comment: simply use `col("b.AVGYTD"),`

Comment: @ozw1z5rd `data_to_merge.AVGYTD`  is ok when `data_to_merge` and `days_currencies_matrix` are completely different dataframes. In your case, you created one of them using some transformations on the other one, thus the error message...

Comment: @blackbishop ok, so it's all about lazy evaluation. And does not this look like a bug? I can agree that Spark sees all the columns of the original DataFrame in currencies_in_merging_data, however, this is bad. It should not see them. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

The 1st `select()` is about the next_df. In fact, in the first case I'm referencing the columns using the joining data frame names, which are not inside the final result.

In the second code I'm correctly referencing the columns using the name assigned to them by `join`, and these are the correct names.

BTW:

This works too:

```
next_df = days_currencies_matrix.alias('a').join( data_to_merge.alias('b') , [ 
          days_currencies_matrix.dt == data_to_merge.RATE_DATE, 
          days_currencies_matrix.CURRENCY_CODE == data_to_merge.CURRENCY_CODE ], 'LEFT')

next_df = next_df.select(next_df.AVGYTD, next_df.AVGWEEK, next_df.ENDMTH)
```

Comment: 'a' and 'b' alias are not used in either the condition list or select clause. Why does this work? Any more explanation?

Comment: It seems that data_to_merge and days_currencies_matrix DataFrames are not aliased. data_to_merge.AVGYTD most likely is resolved as AVGYTD. Using col() function I force the correct name.
The original DataFrames are the same thing, so the column names collide.